# Identity for expansion of grad(cross$(f, g)$) not using Einstein summation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensor-products, cross-product, outer-product

I want to define an identity for the expansion of the gradient of the cross product between two vector fields:

$\nabla(\mathbf{f}\times\mathbf{g})=[\nabla\otimes(\mathbf{f}\times\mathbf{g})]^T=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f_yg_z-f_zg_y) & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(f_yg_z-f_zg_y) & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(f_yg_z-f_zg_y)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f_zg_x-f_xg_z) & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(f_zg_x-f_xg_z) & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(f_zg_x-f_xg_z)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f_xg_y-f_yg_x) & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(f_xg_y-f_yg_x) & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(f_xg_y-f_yg_x)
\end{bmatrix}$

Wolfram Alpha gave me this:

$\nabla(\mathbf{f}\times\mathbf{g})=\mathbf{g}\cdot(\nabla\times\mathbf{f})-\mathbf{f}\cdot(\nabla\times\mathbf{g})$

I think this is wrong because the cross product between two vector fields yields another vector field and the gradient of a vector field is a second-order tensor field. However, the right-hand side from Wolfram Alpha is a scalar field (curl of a vector field yields another vector field and the dot product between two vector fields yields a scalar field). FWIW I entered `del(cross(f, g))` in Wolfram Alpha.

I am looking for an identity in vectorial or matrix-vector notation (not Einstein summation) where the outer product is expanded over $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{g}$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is assuming you want to compute the divergence.

Comment: I somehow got that, the weird thing however is that Wolfram Alpha did not print a $\cdot$. So visually it still looks like a gradient and not a divergence.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122575/covariant-derivatives-and-the-cross-product) and [this (and the link included in the answer)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3244425/what-is-the-covariant-derivative-of-a-wedge-product) answer your question.